# My executable jar can't open resource files when I run it outside of netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

first post here, I hope I've formed this question adequately. My project finds the resource files on the classpath when run inside of netbeans as a project, but when I run the jar outside of netbeans, it can't find the resources (I have checked, and yes they are being placed into the jar.)

I've tried both .getResource() and also a .getResourceAsStream() version of my code. They both succeed when run inside of netbeans as a maven project, but those resources aren't being found when I remove the jar and run it outside of netbeans.

Here's a snippet of my code, and also the snippet from my pom file where I add the resources. It all works when run as a project inside netbeans, but not when I run the jar elsewhere. It fails to find the resources.

... ...

```
    String wholeFile = "";
    try {

       BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader(
                new java.io.InputStreamReader(
                        getClass().getResourceAsStream( sqlFileName ) 
            )
        );

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String strCurrentLine;
        while ( (strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            sb.append( strCurrentLine );
            sb.append( System.getProperty("line.separator") );
        }
        wholeFile = sb.toString();
```

... or, preferably ...

```
        wholeFile = java.nio.file.Files.readString(
            java.nio.file.Paths.get( 
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( sqlFileName ).toURI()
            ) 
        );


    // Split that file into individual create
    // table strings contained in the file.

    // Slit on two newlines.
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String[] tables = wholeFile.split( newLine + newLine );
```

... ...

And here's what I added to the pom. But this only resolves if run in netbeans. Why? What am I missing about the maven setup here? Outside of netbeans ... the executable jar won't locate these resource file like they do when run inside netbeans.

Thanks in advance. I hope my question was clear.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
                <include>**/*.jpg</include>
            </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: The value of sqlFileName and the content of your *.jar would be interesting to compare.

Comment: "CreateTables.txt"  "BasicInserts.txt"  ... and in the jar they are in there, at the root level.

Comment: "/CreateTables.txt" also works ... but outside of netbeans ... neither works.

Comment: inside the jar ... com and META-INF and CreateTables.txt and BasicInserts.txt. They are definitely going into the jar.

Answer (score 0):

`java.nio.file.Files` cannot read the content of *.jar files, as far as I know. You need to access the resource via the class loader as stream. So I think your first attempt should be Ok.

It's possibly just a matter of the path name. Here is a working example without Maven:

File src/de/stefanfrings/Main.java:

```
package de.stefanfrings;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputStream stream=Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(stream);
        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

File src/de/test.txt:

```
Hello
World
```

Content of test.jar:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
test.txt
de/stefanfrings/Main.class
```

Output:

```
java -jar test.jar
Hello
World
```

If I change the filename to "../../test.txt" then it works only in the IDE because the IDE executes the program from the (uncompressed) folder where the compiler places its output.

Try to prefix your filename with "/".

Comment: Thanks. You fixed it. Main.class.getResourceAsStream instead of getClass().getResourceAsStream made all the difference somehow.

Comment: Hmm, I wrote ```Main.class``` because my class is static and hence has no ```getClass()``` method.

Comment: I know, and when I used your way ... I naturally placed GumBDBInsert.class in place of your Main.class ... because it's the name of my class. Now ... it all works, outside of netbeans too. When I use the .getClass() or even the .getClass().getClassLoader() variants, it fails. Using your method, and making it be InputStream stream = GumBDBInsert.class.getResourceAsStream( sqlFileName ); ... made it all work. Can't use the .getClass() methods it seems.

Comment: Ok, as my final comment, and thanks for pointing me toward a solution Stefan, it does work when I use .getClass() now ... in an executable jar away from netbeans. It seems to have something to do with using the simpler InputStream ... here's my final solution. InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream( sqlFileName ); No hardcoding in the class name, so this is the solution here: to use InputStream.

Answer (score -1):

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream( sqlFileName );
            Scanner in=new java.util.Scanner(stream);
            while (in.hasNextLine())
            {
                    //System.out.println(in.nextLine());
                    sb.append( in.nextLine() );
                    sb.append( System.getProperty("line.separator") );
            }
            in.close();
            wholeFile = sb.toString();
```

Thanks so much, that fixed it. There was something different about using just a straight InputStream here. Your code worked.

Works now, ... outside of netbeans too. Thanks so much!

Comment: Usng  a Scanner instead of a BufferedReader doesn't fix this. Scanner uses BufferedReader under the hood. The problrem is in the filename.

Comment: Of course. I used the Scanner here only to give an example how to same some few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Stefan, you pointed me in a direction that, for whatever reason, got this working for me. I'm just using InputStream for now to move forward. I may play around later with the BufferedReader and Files.readString appraoches to see what was going on. But honestly, the first thing I had tried in my initial code I posted was to make sure my file path was prefixed  with a '/' ... /CreateTables.txt ... and it wasn't working. InputStream works for now, so I'm moving forward with that. Thanks again, it works solidly now, away from netbeans in it's executable jar.